# Sound performance in loop

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i am using [soundmanager](http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2008/07/15/as3/as3-soundmanager/) to order sounds.

[my site preview](http://gricreative.com/clients/toca/site), in home page, square shapes comes into stage and you can drag drop them, 
all shapes binded its own sound. if they are colliding binded song will play.

**the problem is** 
i have 3 second timer to control sounds. every timeout i have to stop sound and play again for synchronous issue, that is my solution for that part. but sometimes before loop, there is an annoying little silence. i don't know how to say it in English. can you just check it out.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

look here for how Andre Michelle (the go to guy for audio+flash) dealt with this 
http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2010/playback-mp3-loop-gapless/

Comment: i red it, but i dont understand some parts, i am using wav format and converting it inside flash, how should i import them, Can the class solve my problem.